# python - find a matrix in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I have a dictionary `g` whose items are numpy matrices.

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array(([1,2],[3,4]))
g = {}
g[0] = np.array(([1,2,3],[3,4,5]))
g[1] = np.array(([11,22],[3,4]))
g[2] = np.array(([1,2],[3,4]))
g[3] = np.array(([0,2],[3,0]))
```

and I would like to check whether `h` is in dictionary `g` or not. In this case yes, because `g[2]` is exactly `h`.

Is there any way to look for a matrix inside a dictionary?

Comment: `h in g.values()`?

Comment: `h in g.values()` returns: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the built-in function `numpy.array_equal`?

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to work just fine.
`
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> b = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> numpy.array_equal(a, b)
True
`

Answer (score 1):

This is just extension of what [phg1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612749/phg1024) wrote:

```
any([np.array_equal(h, x) for x in g.values()])
```

Answer (score 1):

All excellent answers. But, if you care about speed (which you really should :)), I think the killer combination to use is `np.any` with a *generator expression*.

```
# use generator comprehension instead of list comprehension
np.any((np.array_equal(h, dict_arr) for dict_arr in g.values()))
```

---

Efficiency (in descending order)

```
# with np.any & generator comprehension
In [126]: %timeit np.any((np.array_equal(h, arr) for arr in g.values()))
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop

# with python's any & generator comprehension
In [129]: %timeit any((np.array_equal(h, arr) for arr in g.values()))
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.6 µs per loop

# with python's any & list comprehension
In [130]: %timeit any([np.array_equal(h, arr) for arr in g.values()])
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.9 µs per loop

# with np.any & list comprehension
In [128]: %timeit np.any([np.array_equal(h, arr) for arr in g.values()])
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.1 µs per loop
```

So, generator comprehension wins, well most of the time!

Comment: Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 0):

I found this slightly dirty solution:

```
any(h in val for val in g.values())
```